# Is there any story of gods being forced to temporarily turn mortal?

Tags: gods

In Greek Mythology, Poseidon and Apollo were forced by Zeus to temporarily turn mortal for trying to overthrow him.

Is there an analogous story in the Hindu myths? Note that I'm not talking about incarnations - I'm talking about situations where the gods were completely turned into mortal state such that their godly state no longer remained, at least temporarily.

Nor am I talking about stories like Sati committing suicide or Kamadeva being destroyed by Shiva -- the deity has to remain in mortal form for some time.

Comment: Yes Gods became mortal temporarily before Samudra Madhanam and there are many instances where a particular Deva lost his divine power,

Comment: Yes there is a story of Nalakuvara and manigriva;the sons of Kuvera being forced to become trees in the yard of Nand Maharaj(foster father of Lord Krishna). You can read the story here http://www.vedabase.com/en/kb/10